# Is there a way to set to do not show "MAS Console" and "Organisation Inspector" in JaCaMo

Tags: agent, multi-agent

In JaCaMo, is there a way to do not show the console windows, I mean, "MAS Console" of Jason and "Organization Inspector" that shows Moise configurations?

My jcm file is as follow:

```
mas auctionAEO {

    agent a : auctioneerAEO.asl {
        beliefs:    total(10)
        roles:      auctioneer in agrp
    } 
    agent p : participantAEO.asl {
        instances:  10
        roles:      participant in agrp
    }

    organisation aorg : auction-os.xml {
        group agrp : auctionGroup {
            debug
        }
    }

    asl-path: src/agt
              src/agt/inc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, JaCaMo uses Jason solution for that, that is based on Java Logging API. You just need to configure another logging handler instead of "MAS Gui Console", just change logging.properties file to do it. You may look for documentation on that in the [Jason FAQ](http://jason.sourceforge.net/faq/#_how_to_log_the_overall_execution).

To disable the org. inspector, just remove the `debug` keyword in the corresponding group.

Comment: In fact, it didn't work because an agent code was telling     "debug(inspector_gui(on))". Removing this instruction it is perfectly working, thanks!